# Unsure how to use border-bottom in CSS

Tags: html, css

what I'd like to achieve is a border-bottom 20px below my h1 tag in my sidebar and also have 20px of "white space" below my border-bottom. I'd also like to have this underneath my h1 tag in my content area.

[Here's the link to what I have now](http://redsky.incredifull.com/)
HTML:

```
<!-- SIDEBAR -->
<div id="sidebar">
<h1>Caul / Cbua</h1>

<div class="sidetext">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam laoreet mi c est dignissim, at auctor mi tristique.
</div>

<h1>Commit</h1>
<div class="sidelink">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div id="content">
<h1>News</h1>

<div class="article">
<img class="articleimg" src="../../Slicing Images/news images/caul.png" width="84" height="65" alt="caul" />

<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<h3>Friday, August 16th</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
</div>

<div class="article">
<img class="articleimg" src="../../Slicing Images/news images/caul.png" width="84" height="65" alt="caul" />

<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<h3>Friday, August 16th</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
background-color: #e7d9c9;
    background-image: url('/imgs/map.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    /* # */
    height: 100%;
width: 318px;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#sidebar h1 {
border-bottom: thick;
border-bottom-width: 75%;
}

.sidetext {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    width:300px;
}

.sidelink ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.sidelink li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidelink li a {
    display:block;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#1e416f;
    padding:5px;
    border-left:10px solid #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink li a:hover {
    border-left:14px solid #1e416f;
    background-color:#e7d9c9;
    color: #1e416f;
}

h5 {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue: Light;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #517f9c;
}

/* Content */
#content {
width: 642px;
float: right;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.article {
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.articleimg {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Just `border-bottom:1px solid black`.

Comment: and `margin-bottom: 20px`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp might help

Comment: @Christoph - please promote other sources than w3schools - MDN for example is much better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Zach L and YaMo i understand your opinions but I think w3schools gives a good overview for basics. I would never recommend mdn simply for the fact that it gives no information about browser support. IMHO a good page should give information about how the different browsers implement something, not how a certain browser implements it or how it should be implemented. Please let me know if you have an acceptable source that informs over most Browsers.

Comment: Browser support for the Box Model? All browsers support it. Upon inspecting the w3schools discussion, its a good example of why its an inferior resource:

"IE8 and earlier versions of IE, included padding and border in the width property. To fix this problem, add a <!DOCTYPE html> to the HTML page."

This is a bit deceptive since ALL pages should have `<!DOCTYPE html>` to conform to the html standard; its not just a "fix" for a problem.

Comment: Check out another page in MDN, describing `border-radius`, which does in fact merit browser support information, and it is provided. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius.

Compare the quality of that page with w3schools': http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

I think its safe to say this is vastly inferior content, and also the volume of advertisements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see how you go

```
#sidebar h1 { border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Comment: Tried this because another person mentioned it :) Thanks. Now how would I go about creating 20px of white space in between the header and the border-bottom?

Comment: you would add `padding-bottom:20px` 

Full example:  `#sidebar h1 { border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom:20px; }`

Comment: or the shorthand version: `#sidebar h1 { border-bottom: 1px solid black; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 0 0 20px 0;}`

Comment: @vzeke even shorter-hand: `#sidebar h1 { border-bottom: 1px #000; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0 0 20px;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
h1 {
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000000;
}
```

AND

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

OR

```
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Combine both rules though...  So more like this:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Michael. You can see it updated on the link I gave. Now how would I go about creating 20px of white space in between the header and the border-bottom?

Comment: Instead of margin, use padding.  padding: 0 0 20px 0; or padding-bottom: 20px;

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
div > h1 { border-bottom: 20px solid black; margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Comment: she wants this on all her `h1`s methinks: "I'd also like to have this underneath my h1 tag in my content area"

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar h1 { border-bottom: 20px solid black; margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

If you want it for all h1

```
h1 { border-bottom: 20px solid black; margin-bottom: 20px; }
```